# Как сделать адаптивный дизайн сайта для телефонов?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Пишу сайт https://onskrer.github.io/YIStroi/ Но на мобильных устройствах он отображается некорректно, контент не во всю ширину экрана. Помогите это исправить пожалуйста, ранее с медиа запросами не работал.

Comment: как минимум задайте всем flex-обёрткам свойство flex-wrap: wrap

Comment: ну и стили слегка поправьте: в кнопке "рассчитать стоимость" явно не хватает паддингов по бокам; блоки с ремонтом разной ширины + отступы по бокам от названий надо увеличить; в форме обратной связи лейблы "имя" и "mail" куда-то съехали совсем.

Comment: flex-wrapов было достаточно. раньше даже не знал об этом свойстве. спасибо

Comment: остальное я Вам просто для улучшения качества предложил

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). Как по мне очень удобный инструмент для быстрой и адаптивной верстки сайта. Документация хорошая и есть много примеров.

Comment: тут другой уровень...
http://prntscr.com/r528a3

Comment: Воу... Ну как хотят)) Можно конечно все это руками делать, но если человек не знаком с медиа, то почему бы не посмотреть как это делают профессионалы (bootstrap)?